# How to randomly spawn enemy within a given bounds using java and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, 2d

Okay so basically i have a Player... its a 2D scroller... i have randomly drawn in spawnArea boxes... basically  when the player is intersecting bounds with the spawnArea for 5 seconds it draws the enemy... my problem is i want to draw the enemy within the bounds of the spawn area...

For example lets say my block for spawnArea is at `(x,y)`
i give it a bounds `(x-150, y-32(sothat its on top of the box), 300 (so that its basically 150 on each side of x, 32);`

how do i draw an enemy randomly within these bounds?

```
if((handler.spawn)&&(handler.getenemyCount()==0)&&(handler.getSpawnCount()==300))
 {
                handler.addObject(new Enemy(x, y-64, 0,handler, ObjectId.Enemy));

///so far this draws the enemy at the top of the  boxes location... i was trying to add a random factor of (x-r.nextInt(100) >> x+r.nextInt(100) to try and make it within a certain area but it wasnt working out...  

ps the Y im not worried about its the random X within the rectangle bounds of the spawn area

                handler.setSpawnCount(0);
                handler.setEnemyCount(1);

            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.draw(getBounds());
            g2d.draw(getBoundsLeft());
            //g2d.draw(getBoundsRight());
            //g2d.draw(getBoundsTop());

    }


    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle((int)x-150 , (int)y-32,300, 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out on my own lol...

basically created a minX and a maxX to reflect my bounds... aka x+150 and x-150

using these two variables i created a random number within them..\

randomNum = r.nextInt((maxX - minX) + 1) + minX; // i put this in the tick so it would be random every time

then inserted the randomNum as the x value for inserting the enemy...